# log4j2 - StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

This is my configuration file:

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">./log</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/mylog.log" filePattern="${log-path}/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p]\t%m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="32" />
    </RollingFile>


    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%n%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p]\t%m</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="mylog" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="DEBUG" />
    </Logger>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But I get the following error:

ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2

How can I solve it?

This is my Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The log configuration file is very clearly read, since it correctly writes using the defined patterns in my /log directory.

This is how I instantiate it in my code:

```
LoggerContext lcontext = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext)  LogManager.getContext(false)
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("mylog");
```

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed this in my Spring Boot app by putting **log4j2.xml** inside `src/main/resources` folder. It STILL gives me the "StatusError No Log4j 2 configuration file found" during compilation, BUT when it is runnung, it ACTUALLY follows my configuration. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a web servlet, you will also need this dependency:

```
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell the system where the log4j2 configuration file is by using `System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", log4j2ConfigFile);`

Comment: is log4j.configurationFile deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had kept the file at src/main/resources. But Log4J was still unable to find it as the JAR created by Maven plugin didn't contain the log4j2.xml file.

To get rid of this problem, I kept the file at root of the folder (just next to pom.xml). Now, when I created a JAR file using Maven Plugin, Log4j could access it. And it worked ! :)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

from **log4j-user-guide 6.1.1 Configuration**:

> 2. if no location...."log4j2" in WEB-INF directory ...

But this does not work (at least in my case). The below one works:

> WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml

Hope this helps.

**Application Server: wildfly 14**